# Do i have to make mutiple blade templates? laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

i am quite new to laravel and blade templates , and i am quite confused what should i do in this situation.

I got mutiple tables - cpus table, motherboards table, memory table etc... each table contains information about parts specifications

I'm retrieving single column from a table

```
  $select_columns = [
   'cores',
   'threads',
   'frequency',
   'max_frequency',
   'l1',
   'l2',
   'l3',
   'thermal',
   'tech',
  ];

  $specs = \DB::table('cpus')->select($select_columns)->where('slug' , $slug)->first();
```

The information about specification and value should be displayed like this.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Specificiation</td> 
<td>value</td>              
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Specification</td> 
<td>value</td>              
</tr>

// other specifications

</tbody>
 </table>
```

I could easily output all tables rows with foreach loop using 1 template.

```
@foreach ($specs as $spec => $value)
<tr>
<td>{{$spec}} </td>  
<td>{{$value}} </td>                
</tr>
@endforeach
```

but the {{spec}} - specificarions needs to be in different language, and i can't use

```
select(column as newvalue)
```

because there are letters like 'Ā Ļ Ņ Ž ' and code would loook really weird if i would do that

So i guess the question is what exactly should i do about it?

Should i make each table a new template and display data like this?

```
<tr>
<td>Specification</td> 
<td>{{$specs->value}}</td>              
</tr>


<tr>
<td>Specification1</td> 
<td>{{$specs->value1}}</td>                 
</tr>
```

I'm quite lost here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `{{ htmlspecialchars($specs->value) }}` ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: What's your problem with those letters? You can't query your database or you can't display data properly?

Comment: What does it have to do with htmlsepcialchars? If i use select(column as newvalue) and i include letters as "Ā Ņ Ž " ill gonna have to use it afterwards in code aswell if i'll have to make some controls for specific $spec->value for example $spec->Kanārijs == true, and it looks kind of weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would not make a separate template for each table. Dry, lazy developer and all those things.

I think the [localization functionality](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/localization) from Laravel might be a good fit here. You could use the keys from your array as keys in your translation files. Perhaps something like this:

```
@foreach ($specs as $spec => $value)
<tr>
<td>{{trans('specs.' . $spec)}} </td>  
<td>{{$value}} </td>                
</tr>
@endforeach
```

And inside you `resources/lang/fr/specs.php` file you you could do something like:

```
return [
 'cpu' => 'çpû',
 // ...
];
```

You could even add additional texts (some sort of description or whatever) based on those keys to enrich your tables even more. And if you ever decide to translate your website to another language you're already halve way there, you just have to add a folder for your new language and copy and translate those files there.

Comment: Thank you, seems thats what i am looking for :)